# How to scale a Mat in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I'm frustrated trying to find a method that would allow me to scale a Mat object to a different size. Please, could anybody help me with this?

My project is using the Java wrapper, but I'll be happy if the answer provided is for the C++ native OpenCV library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If by resizing you mean scaling an image use the [resize()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) function as follows:

```
resize(src, dst, dst.size(), 0, 0, interpolation);
```

Otherwise if you just need to change the number of rows of your Mat use the [Mat::reshape()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) function. Pay attention that the reshape return a new Mat header:

```
cv::Mat dst = src.reshape ( 0, newRowVal );
```

Finally if you want to arbitrarily reshape the Mat (changing rows and cols) you probably need to define a new Mat with the destination dimensions and copy the src Mat to it:

```
Mat dst(newRowVal, newColVal, src.type());
src.setTo(0);
src.copyTo(dst(Rect(Point(0, 0), src.size())));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use  `resize()` function

Create a new Mat result of new dimensions

```
resize(input             // input image 
       result            // result image
       result.size()     // new dimensions
       0, 
       0, 
       INTER_CUBIC       // interpolation method
      );
```

to know more interpolation methods, you can check this doc: [geometric_transformations.html#resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize)